# Fastest way to search through lists in python

Tags: python

I’m sure there’s a standard answer for this. What’s the fastest method to loop over one list, forming a new list that is elements that are a member of a different list. I usually just do list comprehensions, sometimes turning the target list into a set. Hashing the target list usually improves performance when the target list is big, but this is the only improvement I know of. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
list_A=list(range(0,100))
list_B=list(range(50,60))

#List comprehension lookup 
listC=[x for x in list_A if x in list_B]

#Using set
set_B=set(list_B))
listD=[x for x in list_A if x in set_B]
```

Comment: If you are using sets you can just get the intersection of two sets `set(list_A) & set(list_B)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about order, you could hash both

```
set(listA) & set(listB)
```

Otherwise, not much you can do

Comment: Follow up question, is there efficient hashing or is set the most efficient way to implement hashing in python?

Comment: Set is going to be faster than anything you would create as a function of class.

Comment: @Ryan: hashing is used for dicts, which are the basis for nearly *everything* in python. So, they are quite efficient, it's very unlikely to create something better